# How to customize the shortcut that brings up the "search" screen in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell

I using Fedora 24. When you hit 'Super', on the top of the screen, there is a search box allowing type to search. I'd like to add a custom shortcut of it.

It should work like '<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>' to bring up spotlight in Mac OX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screen with the search bar is called the "Overview". And yes, you can customize the key that launches it.

In that Overview search box, type "keyboard". Find the keyboard control panel applet in the results shown, and launch that. On the left of that panel, find "System" and select that. Then, find "Show the Overview" on the right. It will probably say "Super+S" — click that, and then hit your desired key combination (Ctrl+Space, your case.)

[image: Keyboard control panel showing relevant option]

Note that you can also activate this by bringing your mouse to the "hot corner" in the top left.